# AJAX for loop not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I try to use for loop inside an AJAX callback, but I can't get it to work.

```
function swapsite(e){
  $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "../queryadmin.inc.php",
              data: {site:e}
            }).done(function( msg ) {
             console.log(msg);
             var result=JSON.parse(msg);
             console.log("----------------");
             console.log(result);
              $('#draggable').html("<p id='article"+result[0]['id']+"'>"+result[0]['title']+"</p>");
              var i=0;
              for(i=2,i<=7,i++) $('#draggable'+i).html("<p id='article"+result[i]['id']+"'>"+result[i]['title']+"</p>");

            });

  }
```

The problem is with the line starting with **for**

Comment: What is not working? Check your console for errors. And post some more code. The code you've shown us looks ok except for that you have to use semicolons `;` in `for` loop (typo when posting the question?).

Comment: Use semicolons **;**, not commas **,** in the **for**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's incorrect syntax for a Javascript `for` loop. You need to use semi-colons and not commas:

```
for(var i=2; i<=7; i++)
```

Correct syntax from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for):

```
for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
   statement
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused, why wouldn't it be?

Comment: Lack of semicolons **will** break the code obviously. +1. Perhaps you should write that it is incorrect because of commas instead of semicolons.

Comment: Thanks. I'll accept the answer if SO allows to.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't notice the semi-colon change, I thought you commented about the missing `var`. This is why always add explations to your answer right away. +1 anyway.